# Is there any tool to get log of Tizen devices like Android ddms tools?

Tags: tizen

I want to get log of Tizen devices in order to view log of Application I installed in it.
Is there any tool can do that? Someone likes Android ddms tool

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could run `sdb dlog` from the command line. The SDK IDE also has a log viewer, but I haven't tried it with a physical Tizen device.

Comment: What log do you mean, It has an applog within the IDE

Answer (score 1):

I haven't developed for Android, but there are commands you can run via Putty (or from a shell on the device) or such which will list all apps running at the Linux level and you can run a command to get list all of the apps running under Tizen.  I think that it is something like
wrt-launcher -l
Something like that.  If it's the right one, it will list all of the applications and their ID's.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your suggest. I finally found my answer by running "sdb dlog > file_name" or using Tizen IDE.